# How to loop through array of objects and replace value es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects

```
const array =[{ 
    "id": 1,
    "time": "2021-09-22T05:36:22.484Z"
},
 {​
   ​"id": 2,
   ​"time": "2021-10-22T03:25:26.484Z"
}]
```

I want to replace all the time values after converting to a timezone.

I am able to convert to timezones using

```
moment.tz("time","America/Toronto").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)
```

but not sure how to loop through to replace the time value of every object.

So ideally, I would have something like:

```
const array =[{ 
    "id": 1,
    "time": "2021-09-22 15:00"
},
 {​
   ​"id": 2,
   ​"time": "2021-10-22T 12:00"
}]
```

Comment: [Loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) or [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: `array.map(({ time, ...args }) => ({ time: moment(...), ...args }))`

Answer (score 4):

Based on your data, you could simple use `forEach` and manipulate the time property as per your needs.

```
const array =[
  {  "id": 1, "time": "2021-09-22T05:36:22.484Z" }, 
  {  "id": 2, "time": "2021-10-22T03:25:26.484Z" },
]

array.forEach(x => {
  x.time = moment(x.time).utcOffset(90).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()` to loop over the array and create a new array with the updated data.

```js
const array = [{
  "id": 1,
  "time": "2021-09-22T05:36:22.484Z"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "time": "2021-10-22T03:25:26.484Z"
}]

const result = array.map(({id, time}) => {
  return {
    id,
    time: moment(time).utcOffset(90).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array=array.map(ar=>{
ar.time=  convertedtimezone
//convert ar.time into timezone and assign it to ar.time
return ar
)
```

Comment: If you're modifying the original object, you should use a `forEach` instead of a `map`…

Comment: okay Thanks got it, can you tell me why

Comment: 'Cause it's unnecessary to create a new array here, if the change is reflected in the original array anyway.

Comment: forEach manipulates the current object. Map on the other hand returns a new object without mutating the current object iterated on.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[{  "id": 1, "time": "2021-09-22 15:00" }, {"id": 2,"time": "2021-10-22T 12:00" }].map(ele=>{return {...ele,time:moment.tz(ele.time,"America/Toronto").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)}})
```